# Find maximum element from the given array of integers

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, mixed

Input format:
First line of input contains N - size of the array and second line contains the elements of the array

Constraints:

1<=N <= 100
-109<= ar[i]<= 109

Output format:
Print the maximum element of the given array

Comment: Can you please give a simple example how your input and output looks exactly? The description is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.